# how to write a program to reverse character letter in uppercase and lowercase [C++]

Tags: c++

This is what I have tried and the output is smileface characters.
Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks

```
#include<iostream>
#include<ctype.h>
using namespace std; 

int main() {
    string userInput = {};

    cout << "Please enter in a string\n";
    cin >> userInput;
    for (int i = 0; i <= userInput.size(); i++) {
        if (userInput[i] == islower(userInput[i])) {
            userInput[i] = isupper(userInput[i]);
        }
        else userInput[i] = islower(userInput[i]);
    };
    cout << userInput << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There are several errors in the code, but reading the docs for [`islower`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/islower) would be a good place to start.

Answer (score 1):

islower only returns a boolean which evaluates to true if the character is lower case and vice versa for isupper. You typically do not assign a result from islower or is upper. You assign a result from toupper and tolower, those functions return the upper or lower form of c.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std; 

int main() {
    string userInput = {};

    cout << "Please enter in a string\n";
    cin >> userInput;
   char c;
int i(0);
      while (userInput[i])
  {
    c=userInput[i];
    if (isupper(c)) 
    c=tolower(c);
    else if(islower(c)) 
    c=toupper(c);
    putchar (c); //prints c on console
    i++;
  }
    //cout << userInput << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you realise this, but in ASCII the difference between uppercase and lowercase is exactly 32: e.g. 'A" has ASCII value 65, while 'a' has 97.

So, in order to switch from one to the other, you jusr perform a XOR 32:

```
'A' XOR 32 = 'a"
'a' XOR 32 = 'A'
```

I don't know the exact c++ syntax for this, but shouldn't be too hard to find.